# Port number not showing in headers.host

Tags: python, request, port

I am making an HTTP request from frontend and I can see the port number in Host field of request Headers in dev tools (eg xyz.com:1234). But using python's requests module, host only shows xyz.com.
How can I get the port number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `requests` library does not need to create and add a `Host` header when you use it to make a request, but you can add a `Host` header if you want: just provide the [`headers` keyword argument](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers)--e.g. `headers={'Host': 'xyz.com:1234'}` if using your example above.

#### Parsing a port number from a URL, a manual approach

Your question seems to be more tied to parsing a port number for a request, however, and for that an example should clear things up for you:

```py
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import requests

def get_port(url: str) -> int:
    schema_ports = {'http': 80, 'https': 443}
    parsed_url = urlparse(url)
    if parsed_url.port:
        return parsed_url.port
    return schema_ports.get(parsed_url.scheme, None)

ports = (
    get_port(requests.get('http://localhost:8001').request.url),
    get_port(requests.get('http://google.com').request.url),
    get_port(requests.get('https://google.com').request.url)
)

print(ports) # (8001, 80, 443)
```

In this example, there are three HTTP GET requests with the `requests` library. Although in this contrived example you already see the request URL, if you are working on a solution from a generic `requests.models.Response` object you can get the request URL from the `request.url` attribute. You then need to realize in cases where no port is specified explicitly, you will need to infer a reasonable default (as there is no explicit `port`). The `get_port` definition above gives an example of this for two common schemes (HTTP and HTTPS).

Read about Python's standard library's [urllib.parse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) module for more information.

#### A more automated approach, leaning on the standard library

The manual approach described above describes how to think about this problem in a generic sense, but it does not scale easily to the many common schemes that may exist (`ssh`, `gopher`, etc.).

On POSIX systems, the `/etc/services` file maintains mappings for common service schemes to ports/protocols and optional descriptions, e.g.

```
http             80/udp     www www-http # World Wide Web HTTP
http             80/tcp     www www-http # World Wide Web HTTP
```

The [`getservbyname` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.getservbyname) in Python's `socket` library has a way to tap into this type of mapping:

```
>>> socket.getservbyname('https')
443
>>> socket.getservbyname('http')
80
```

With this, we can refine my first example to avoid manually specifying mappings for common schemes:

```py
import socket
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import requests

def get_port(url: str) -> int:
    parsed_url = urlparse(url)
    if parsed_url.port:
        return parsed_url.port
    try:
        return socket.getservbyname(parsed_url.scheme)
    except OSError:
        return None

ports = (
    get_port(requests.get('http://localhost:8001').request.url),
    get_port(requests.get('http://google.com').request.url),
    get_port(requests.get('https://google.com').request.url)
)

print(ports) # (8001, 80, 443)
```